# boosting and un-pruned decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, bias, boosting

I have seen a lot of people claiming Boosting is used to reduce bias. Does it mean achieving high training accuracy, which could be achieved by un-pruned decision tree? Could anyone correct me where I misunderstand?

Comment: Do you know about the bias-variance decomposition of expected test set error?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Yes, I know that. But how to use that theorem to explain my confusion?

Comment: Yup. The main point of boosting is to carefully lower the bias of your model *while keeping the variance under control*. While you get match the *training* error of a boosted model with a single deep decision tree, the tree will have much higher variance, driving the *test* error to be higher.

Comment: Hi Matthew, do you mean reducing individual tree's depth to control variance of boosting model? Since I have seen some cases that both bagging and boosting don't show much better improvements compared with common decision tree and other types of base models, I am kind of curious about when these ensemble learning could have great power and when not. Kindly advise me if you have any thoughts. Thx

Comment: I'm making statements as if they are absolutely true, but of course, they are not. Generally, a well constructed (small learning rate, early stopping on the number of trees, grid search the shallow depths of the individual trees) gradient boosted model will out perform a single decision tree on a test set, but not always. I doubt there is a way to cleanly characterize in which situation the single tree will win (on test error). When in doubt, you can just try, fitting a single tree is thankfully a relatively simple exercise.

Comment: Thank you, matthew!